# Java Understanding Math.getExponent(Double)

Tags: java, number-formatting

```
Double dble = new Double("2.2737367544323201e-13");
int exponent = Math.getExponent(dble);
```

I have the above code and exponent has value of '-43'. I'm not sure how the exponent is '-43', when the passed double value contains '-13'. Could someone shed some light into this API?

Comment: It is the exponent for the number in base 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.getExponent()` returns the exponent of the binary representation of the number. In your example -13 is the exponent of the decimal representation, and -43 the exponent of the binary representation.

For example,

```
System.out.println (Math.getExponent (1024));
```

prints

```
10
```

since

```
1024 = 2 ^ 10
```

so the exponent is 10.

```
System.out.println (Math.getExponent (1.0/8192));
```

will print

```
-13
```

since

```
1.0/8192 = 2 ^ (-13)
```